# Optimize query for table with hundreds of millions of rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

this feels like a "do my homework for me" kind of question but I'm really stuck here trying to make this query run quickly against a table with many many rows. [Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82d23/2/1) that shows the schema (more or less).

I've played with the indexes, trying to get something that will show all the required columns but haven't had much success. Here's the `create`:

```
CREATE TABLE `AuditEvent` (
    `auditEventId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eventTime` datetime NOT NULL,
    `target1Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `target1Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `target2Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `target2Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `clientId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `type` int(11) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`auditEventId`),
    KEY `Transactions` (`clientId`,`eventTime`,`target1Id`,`type`),
    KEY `TransactionsJoin` (`auditEventId`, `clientId`,`eventTime`,`target1Id`,`type`)
)
```

And (a version of) the `select`:

```
select ae.target1Id, ae.type, count(*)
from AuditEvent ae
where ae.clientId=4
    and (ae.eventTime between '2011-09-01 03:00:00' and '2012-09-30 23:57:00')
group by ae.target1Id, ae.type;
```

I end up with a 'Using temporary' and 'Using filesort' as well. I tried dropping the `count(*)` and using `select distinct` instead, which doesn't cause the 'Using filesort'. This would probably be okay if there was a way to `join` back to get the counts.

Originally, the decision was made to track the target1Name and target2Name of the targets as they existed when the audit record was created. I need those names as well (the most recent will do).

Currently the query (above, with missing target1Name and target2Name columns) runs in about 5 seconds on ~24million records. Our target is in the hundreds of millions and we'd like the query to continue to perform along those lines (hoping to keep it under 1-2 minutes, but we'd like to have it much better), but my fear is once we hit that larger amount of data it won't (work to simulate additional rows is underway).

I'm not sure of the best strategy to get the additional fields. If I add the columns straight into the `select` I lose the 'Using index' on the query. I tried a `join` back to the table, which keeps the 'Using index' but takes around 20 seconds.

I did try changing the eventTime column to an int rather than a datetime but that didn't seem to affect the index use or time.

Comment: What is your current query timing and what do you understand under "quickly"?

Comment: Do you have indexes on clientId and eventTime? Also verify that if you have those that you are using the eventTime index and are not doing a full table scan.

Comment: Did you  tried something from the following workaround: 1) changing DATETIME to INT; 2) making partition by client_id; 3) What about data actuality: is it possible that data have a time to live and than it could be moved to a kind of history table?

Comment: @NatanCox All the indexes I have tried are in the CREATE statement. When I EXPLAIN on that query it says it is using the index (if you go to the SQLFiddle it will run the EXPLAINs).

Comment: @ravnur I would like to try partitioning on the client id, we have had better performance on clients that have fewer records. Unfortunately, this is the projected amount of online data we are required to have. I will try changing DATETIME to INT and see what comes out.

Comment: Why don't you have a key on `clientId`? Because this is the most specific criteria you have.

Comment: How come no one ever mentions the storage engine used and hardware behind everything? There's only so much one can do by setting every index right, the rest is up to the hardware. And not using InnoDB with large buffer_pool means lots of disk IO and on a mechanical drive with ~400ish IOPS - of course that performance on a multi-million row will be awful.

Comment: you may consider a materialized view. (god forbid i suggest denormalizing the totals.)

Comment: @OlafDietsche MySQL will use the compound index to satisfy clientId.

Comment: @N.B. I'm definitely fuzzy around DB engine/config optimization. I will tweak the InnoDB settings, can you recommend anything guide-wise besides the MySQL docs?

Comment: @NickSpacek - [here is some interesting reading](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings), but mostly what you want to do is increase variable called `innodb_buffer_pool` - I usually have it at about 90% of the available RAM. The other thing is that you should have fast disk subsystem capable of more than 500 IOPS (SSDs annihilate mechanical drives there, ranging from 40k IOPS upwards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably understand, the problem here is the range condition `ae.eventTime between '2011-09-01 03:00:00' and '2012-09-30 23:57:00'` which (as it always does) breaks efficient usage of `Transactions` index (that is index is actually used only for `clientId` equation and first part of the range condition and the index is not used for grouping).

Most often, the solution is to replace the range condition with an equality check (in your case, introduce a `period` column, group `eventTime` into periods and replace the `BETWEEN` clause with a `period IN (1,2,3,4,5)`). But this might become an overhead for your table.

Another solution that you might try is to add another index (probably replace `Transactions` if it is not used anymore): `(clientId, target1Id, type, eventTime)`, and use the following query:

```
SELECT
  ae.target1Id,
  ae.type,
  COUNT(
    NULLIF(ae.eventTime BETWEEN '2011-09-01 03:00:00' 
                            AND '2012-09-30 23:57:00', 0)
  ) as cnt,
FROM AuditEvent ae
WHERE ae.clientId=4
GROUP BY ae.target1Id, ae.type;
```

That way, you will a) move the range condition to the end, b) allow using the index for the grouping, c) make the index the *covering index* for the query (that is the query does not need disk IO operations)

**UPD1:**
I am sorry, yesteday I did not carefully read your post and did not notice that your problem is to retrieve `target1Name` and `target2Name`. First of all, I am not sure that you correctly understand the meaning of `Using index`. The absence of `Using index` does not mean that no index is used for the query, `Using index` means that the index itself contains enough data to execute a subquery (that is the index is covering). Since `target1Name` and `target2Name` are not included in any index, the subquery that fetches them wil not have `Using index`.

If you question is just how to add those two fields to your query (which you consider fast enough), then just try the following:

```
SELECT a1.target1Id, a1.type, cnt, target1Name, target2Name
FROM (
  select ae.target1Id, ae.type, count(*) as cnt, MAX(auditEventId) as max_id
  from AuditEvent ae
  where ae.clientId=4
      and (ae.eventTime between '2011-09-01 03:00:00' and '2012-09-30 23:57:00')
  group by ae.target1Id, ae.type) as a1
JOIN AuditEvent a2 ON a1.max_id = a2.auditEventId
;
```

Comment: Both are valid answers actually; I was looking to increase performance of the query / get advice on different ways to structure it, and additionally I was wonder the best way to retrieve the non-indexed columns. Both of your suggestions have improved performance compared to the queries I have tried!